# Algorithm to find maximum value of ax + b for different values of x

Tags: algorithm, math

Imagine an array **A** of size **n**, where each array element contains two positive integers **a<sub>i</sub>** and **b<sub>i</sub>**.

There are Q queries where each query can be one of two types:

1) Given a positive integer **x**, find **max (a<sub>i</sub>x + b<sub>i</sub>)** for all **i** from **1** to **n**

2) Update values of **a<sub>i</sub>** and **b<sub>i</sub>** for some **i**

The number of queries can be large hence the naive `O(Q * n)` algorithm wouldn't suffice. Also, x can be as large as 10<sup>9</sup> and the value of the objective expression can be as large as 10<sup>18</sup>.

Can this be solved using some variation of segment trees? If there is a similar question around please point me to it. Also, how would you go about solving this one? I am not looking for code, only some hints / pointers to the logic.

**Edit**: You can assume that values of **x** in query type 1 are non decreasing.

**Edit 2**: You can assume that in the updates, the value of **a** only increases.

**Edit 3**: I have found the answer to my question [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10894/dynamic-upper-envelope-of-lines-in-the-plane). Thanks to @Mikhail for pointing out the word *envelope*. Using that word too many times did help ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: @erip does it belong to math SE ?

Comment: What is bigger, `n` or `Q`?

Comment: @Mikhail 1 <= n <= 10^5, 1 <= Q <= 10^5

Comment: I disagree - this question belongs to this site. Questions about algorithms are on topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because CS theory; not a programming problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @Sorin's idea is right, but finding of intersection points is inefficient. What you want to is to construct an *upper envelope* of all your lines. This envelope will contain not more than `N-1` points (each line can contribute not more than once in the envelope). So scanning through its sorted points will take `O(N+Q)` time.

[image]

Now, we will construct the envelope in `O(NlogN)` time. First of all, sort all lines with ascending `a`. This will take `O(NlogN)`. Let's assume for simplicity that all values of `a` are different, this will not change the main idea.

Note that lines `0` and `N-1` will form the left and right slopes of the envelope. Because near infinity, constant `b` does not mater. So let's start with line `0`, as a first segment of the envelope. Now we will go through all other lines in the order of ascending `a`, updating the envelope on each step. How many more times am I going to repeat "the envelope"? Hmm...

The update of the envelope (damn!) is quite similar to how [Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) works. At first step we put line `0` in the stack. On each step, we consider the next line and throw away all lines from the top of the stack, until the new line fits. See the image:

[image]

Here we add line `i+1`. For this we need to throw away lines `i` and `i-1`. Since each line is added to this stack and removed from it not more than once, the whole scan takes only `O(N)`. As you can see, the sorting takes all the time.

Wonder how to decide whether the next line fits into the current stack? Compare points of intersections of lines `i+1` over `i` and `i` over `i-1`.

Now that we have the envelope (I swear, this is the last time), the rest is easy. We have solution working in O(Q+NlogN). HTH.

By the way, I was pointed out that this algorithm is quite popular and is called a [Convex hull trick](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Convex_hull_trick).

**UPD** Wow, I forget that we also need to update the envelope from time to time :) This complicates the problem. Need to think about it.

Anyway, in contrast to the naive approach, which handles queries of type 1 in `O(N)` and of type 2 in `O(1)`, this offers the opposite: `O(1)` for type 1, `O(N)` for type 2.

Comment: That is a good idea! Though we also have to handle updates. Updates are basically removal of a line and addition of another line which would change the envelope.

Comment: @Rushil Wow, I completely forgot about that! :) Anyway, hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed solution! and about the updates, I'll make it slightly easier, the line that gets updated will have increased slope. intercept may increase or decrease. I'll post a solution if I get the update part.

Comment: @Rushil Perhaps. you should state this update in the question.

Comment: I have made some edits.

Comment: @Rushil "Using that word too many times did help" - LOL :)))) Good job finding this! Will check this out too. Spent quite some time figuring this out, so I'm intrigued.

Answer (score 3):

Order the x values first.
Sort the values the lines (ax + b is a line) according to the values at x0 (lowest x).
For every pair of consecutive lines figure out their intersection points (more precisely the x coordinate of the intersection point). If the x coordinate is lower than x0 you can ignore the pair. For the other pairs keep a priority queue to find the next intersection point.

Now, for all the input x before the next intersection point you output the current leading line. Since there are no intersections the order will not change so it's the same line for all of them. When you reach an intersection point that means two of your lines have crossed. So swap them in the sorted list and add again the intersection point with the new neighbours.

Repeat until you have solved all the input cases.
If you run out of intersection points it means that there will not be any other order changes so output the curent max for all the other inputs.

Complexity is likely lead by the initial sort, if the number of lines is relatively small or the number of updates you have to do which is N^2/2 (every line intersect every other line), O(QlogQ + N^2*logN)

Comment: This idea is pretty good, though I will have to try to make it more efficient as N^2 is not good.